# Setting up a Docker compose for Mysql and Vitess

Tags: mysql, docker

With the recent announcement of Planetscale shutting down its lower and free tiers I've found myself in a bit of a situation.

I have a Serverless app which is connected to a Mysql database in Planetscale and it's still not making enough money for me to justify the $40 price tag that Planetscale now offers.

I've set up a VPS with Docker and have started a Mysql container with the following `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: "3.8" 

services:
  mysql-container:
    image: ubuntu/mysql
    container_name: mysql
    volumes:
      - /docker-volumes/mysql/mysql-volume:/var/lib/mysql
      - /docker-volumes/mysql/config:/etc/mysql/conf.d
    environment:
      - TZ=UTC
    ports:
      - "127.0.0.1:3306:3306"
    network_mode: host
    restart: unless-stopped
```

This works great, I can connect to it and my data is persisted. However, a couple of times throughout the day I'll get issues connecting to it because it's exhausted connections from Serverless functions.

I'm aware that Planetscale used to get around this with [Vitess](https://vitess.io) so I tried setting it up myself as a docker container.

I have found this [official guide on setting up Vitess in Docker](https://github.com/vitessio/vitess/blob/main/examples/compose/README.md), however it seems like a huge docker-compose and I can't quite tell if it's something I should be using in production or not.

According to the Readme it starts the following applications as well:

- vtctld web ui: http://localhost:15000
- vttablets web ui: http://localhost:15101/debug/status http://localhost:15102/debug/status http://localhost:15103/debug/status
- vtgate web ui: http://localhost:15099/debug/status
- vtorc ui: http://localhost:13000

I can't quite tell if these are for development, either way all of them give me 404 aside from `vttablets`, which are marked as `healthy`.

Logs from docker seem to repeat the following on a loop, so obviously I've done something wrong:

```
vitess-dev-vreplication-1                    | + /vt/bin/vtctldclient --server vtctld:15999 GetTablets
vitess-dev-vreplication-1                    | + grep ext_
vitess-dev-vreplication-1                    | + grep primary
vitess-dev-vreplication-1                    | + echo 'waiting for external primary..'
vitess-dev-vreplication-1                    | + sleep 1
vitess-dev-vreplication-1                    | waiting for external primary..
vitess-dev-vtorc-1                           | E0308 09:45:30.636448       8 analysis_dao.go:414] ignoring keyspace ext_my_database because no durability_policy is set. Please set it using SetKeyspaceDurabilityPolicy
vitess-dev-vttablet100-1                     | I0308 09:45:30.972908       7 tablegc.go:215] TableGC - started execution of Close. Acquiring initMutex lock
vitess-dev-vttablet100-1                     | I0308 09:45:30.973006       7 tablegc.go:218] TableGC - acquired lock
vitess-dev-vttablet100-1                     | I0308 09:45:30.973013       7 tablegc.go:220] TableGC - no collector is open
vitess-dev-vttablet100-1                     | I0308 09:45:30.973016       7 engine.go:92] messager Engine - started execution of Close. Acquiring mu lock
vitess-dev-vttablet100-1                     | I0308 09:45:30.973149       7 engine.go:94] messager Engine - acquired mu lock
vitess-dev-vttablet100-1                     | I0308 09:45:30.973162       7 engine.go:97] messager Engine is not open
vitess-dev-vreplication-1                    | + /vt/bin/vtctldclient --server vtctld:15999 GetTablets
```

I'm really only interested in the connection pooling functionality of Vitess, is there a minimal example on how to set this up myself anywhere?

Does setting up and using Vitess require further knowledge of database/network internals? Is this something I shouldn't attempt to set up myself?

Comment: the ports part is wrong `    ports:
      # <Port exposed> : <MySQL Port running inside container>
      - '3306:3306'`

Comment: What do you mean? The Mysql compose works fine?